# unable to see VM template from Hyper -v 2 during collection creation on connection broker

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2012-r2

[image]

I have two Hyper-v host server, hyper-v 1 & 2. During collection creation on connection broker, I can see VM Template from hyper-v 1 but I am unable to see any VM Templates from Hyper-V 2.

I have tried re-installing Host role for the Hyper-v server and re-booted Hyper-v  and connection broker 4 times.